# Encryption sensitive data to disk and decrypting to use in powershell

Tags: powershell

So I am generating a `Key`:

```
# Generate 32bit Key 
try
{
    [Byte[]]$key = (1 .. 32)
    [Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
    if (Test-Path $KeyFile)
    {
        get-Content -Path $KeyFile
    }
    else
    {
        $Key | out-file $KeyFile -Force
    }
    attrib +s +h $KeyFile
}
catch
{
    $ectp, $msg = $_.Exception.Message.split(':')
    InfoWrite("config: error: $($msg)")
    WriteEventLog -eventString "config: error: $($msg)" -entryType Error
}
```

I then use this key to encrypt sensitive data (usernames, passwords):

```
if (Test-Path $SecureName)
{
    ConvertTo-SecureString $UserNameTextBox.Text -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key | Set-Content -Path $file
}
else
{
    ConvertTo-SecureString $UserNameTextBox.Text -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key | out-file $file -Force
}
```

Now I would like to use the credentials in a credential object:

```
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR((Get-Content $SecureName | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content $KeyFile )))
$UserName = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
$global:UserCredential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, (Get-Content $SecurePass | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content $KeyFile))
```

I then do a little test to confirm creds:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Credential $UserCredential -properties * -filter *
```

It fails here with invalid credentials, `The server has rejected the client credentials`, however, I know they are correct as I validate them prior to saving them to disk. So I must be doing something fundamentally incorrect, somewhere in this process. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I can see one issue - when you save ```$Key``` to a file it's being converted to lines of ASCII codes, not saved as a binary file. When you read it back in with ```Get-Content``` it's reading an array of strings, not the original binary key. You'll either need to encode the key (e.g. ```[Convert]::ToBase64String```) before you save it, or use something like ```[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes``` so the key data roundtrips to disk properly. Open the keyfile in notepad and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have worked out what the problem was. When I was saving the file content to disk I was pulling the wrong source (DOH!). It is working fine now with the above code.

Comment: Skip the `SecureStringToBSTR` and `PtrToStringAuto` steps - `Get-Content ... |ConvertTo-SecureString` is all you need